# No rows returned when calling stored procedure although running code in that very SP returns rows

Tags: sql, permissions, procedure, enterprise

Whenever I call a stored procedure that contains more than a single select statement I get no rows in the resultset although running the same code outside the SP returns the expected result. This has started happening by the time a database backup from a production environment was installed on the development server.

The example below returns no rows when run in Enterprise Manager 2008:

```
exec dbo.USP_S_CustomerLimit '00000053-0000-1148-5300-000000000000'
```

If I however execute all the code in that procedure by itself (like select it and press "run") I get the expected amount of result rows:

```
SELECT * FROM CustomerLimit WHERE Department =
(SELECT Department FROM Customer WHERE CustomerID = CONVERT(BINARY(16), CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, '00000053-0000-1148-5300-000000000000')))
```

I have also tried this variant of the code which unfortunately behaves in exactly the same way:

```
SELECT CustomerLimit.* FROM CustomerLimit
JOIN Customer ON Customer.Department = CustomerLimit.Department
WHERE Customer.CustomerID = CONVERT(BINARY(16), CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, '00000053-0000-1148-5300-000000000000'))
```

I feel it's some sort of right issue but I don't know where to check. I am db_owner on the server and I also belong to a group that is db_owner in the database in question. What could be the cause of this problem? If I create a testprocedure with just one select, f.e `Select * from Customer` then I get the correct result when executing that procedure but if I write f.e `Select * from Customer where CustomerID in (select CustomerID from Customer)` then I get no rows.. :(

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have rights/permission on all these three tables. Check the sys.objects for the listing of these tables.